# assign unique value to div using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this:

```
function dynamicSet() {
    introNewSection.innerHTML += '<div class="col-lg-5 mb-lg-0 mb-4" id="intro">
}
```

but I want to dynamically set the id. so instead of intro, I was it that everything this funciton is called, it gives the new iteration of this `innerHTML` a unique value. Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is, what you tried so far ?

Comment: `introNewSection.innerHTML += \`<div class="col-lg-5 mb-lg-0 mb-4" id="intro_${Date.now()}">\`
 `